# Python list transpose and fill

Tags: python, list, fill, transpose

I have a list of lists such that the length of each inner list is either 1 or n (assume n > 1).

```
>>> uneven = [[1], [47, 17, 2, 3], [3], [12, 5, 75, 33]]
```

I want to transpose the list, but instead of truncating the longer list (as with `zip`) or filling the shorter lists with `None`, I want to fill the shorter lists with their own singular value. In other words, I'd like to get:

```
>>> [(1, 47, 3, 12), (1, 17, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 75), (1, 3, 3, 33)]
```

I can do this with a couple of iterations:

```
>>> maxlist = len(max(*uneven, key=len))
>>> maxlist
4
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> uneven2 = [x if len(x) == maxlist else repeat(x[0], maxlist) for x in uneven]
>>> uneven2
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [47, 17, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3], [12, 5, 75, 33]]
>>> zip(*uneven2)
[(1, 47, 3, 12), (1, 17, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 75), (1, 3, 3, 33)]
```

But is there a better approach? Do I really need to know `maxlist` in advance to accomplish this?

Comment: You could simulate `itertools.izip_longest`, just using the last value of the sequence instead of a `fillvalue` when the sequence is exhausted.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan is right have saw this link http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html maybe you could also use some other functions from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can repeat one element list forever:

```
uneven = [[1], [47, 17, 2, 3], [3], [12, 5, 75, 33]]

from itertools import repeat

print zip(*(repeat(*x) if len(x)==1 else x for x in uneven))
```

Comment: This was very helpful because the n=1 inner lists were manufactured. Now I've refactored so the list is `[repeat(1), [47, 17, 2, 3], repeat(3), [12, 5, 75, 33]]` and I can just do `zip(*uneven)`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`itertools.cycle()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) instead:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> uneven3 = [x if len(x) != 1 else cycle(x) for x in uneven]
>>> zip(*uneven3)
[(1, 47, 3, 12), (1, 17, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 75), (1, 3, 3, 33)]
```

That means you don't need to know `maxlist` ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked @chris-morgan's idea of simulating `itertools.izip_longest`, so when I finally had the inspiration, I wrote an `izip_cycle` function.

```
def izip_cycle(*iterables, **kwargs):
    """Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
    If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in by cycling the shorter iterables.
    If an iterable is empty, missing values are fillvalue or None if not specified.
    Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.
    """
    fillvalue = kwargs.get('fillvalue')
    counter = [len(iterables)]
    def cyclemost(iterable):
        """Cycle the given iterable like itertools.cycle, unless the counter has run out."""
        itb = iter(iterable)
        saved = []
        try:
            while True:
                element = itb.next()
                yield element
                saved.append(element)
        except StopIteration:
            counter[0] -= 1
            if counter[0] > 0:
                saved = saved or [fillvalue]
                while saved:
                    for element in saved:
                        yield element
    iterators = [cyclemost(iterable) for iterable in iterables]
    while iterators:
        yield tuple([next(iterator) for iterator in iterators])

print list(izip_cycle([], range(3), range(6), fillvalue='@'))
```